# How to make QTextEdit with no visible border?

Tags: qt, styles, qt3

When I create a deafult QTextEdit widget, it appears in a default Windows style border. I don't want this border, so I try to turn it off. How do I do that?

I'm using pretty old version of Qt (3.2.3).

Comment: You can try QTextEdit::setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If i understand the question correctly, you can set the frame style to no frame using the [setFrameStyle()](http://doc.qt.digia.com/3.2/qframe.html#setFrameStyle) function.

Heres an example:

```
QTextEdit *text_edit = new QTextEdit(this);
text_edit->setFrameStyle(QFrame::NoFrame);
```

Answer (score 0):

**To remove the border from a specific Object**

---

- Go to your Object's **Properties** in the UI
- Open the **styleSheet** property
- Add `border: 0;` and Click **Ok**.

**To remove the border from all QTextEdit Objects in a specific Window**

---

Let's do it for the MainWindow for example
In the MainWindow **UI** >>  **Properties** >> **styleSheet**

**Add** this code

```
QTextEdit
{
    border: 0;
}
```

After, You can notice that the border has already gone in the Preview (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>).